# Select module claiming that at most 3 arguments can be accepted (no optional timeout)

Tags: python, select, timeout, nonblocking

I'm attempting to write a program that waits for readline input, but only for a limited span of time for non-blocking input. From another question on stackoverflow, I was alerted to the Select module. It seemed to fit the bill for me. However, when I attempt to implement it, as follows:

```
i,o,e = select([sys.stdin],[],[],5)
```

as described in docs.python.org, (I'm only interested in input, and in this example, a timeout of 5 seconds) I get an error message reading:

```
TypeError: select() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

If I instead call it as:

```
i,o,e = select([sys.stdin],[],[])
```

Then I get:

```
ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
```

with a calling module of /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/function_base.py line 718.
I'm running ubuntu 11.10, with Python 2.7.2+.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I really need the timeout functionality.

Comment: Probably you're using star imports (i.e. `from modulename import *`). It's dangerous, as you have seen.

Comment: my import call reads simply "import select", should this be instead `from select import select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're calling the numpy.[select](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) function , but you want the [select.select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) function. Import them accordingly.

Comment: my import call reads simply "import select" my function call now reads `i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],5)` and I now get an error message informing me `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'select'`

Comment: maybe you're still doing `from numpy import *` ? If so, factor out this code in its own module where you're not importing numpy stuff, or don't import *.

Comment: the characters "numpy" do not appear anywhere in my code, Is that an implicit call that does not need to be stated? Also, I do avoid `import *`

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I simply needed to do `import select` , then call it with `select.select()`. Thank you so much for your help.